# What is this wooden animals game with unique dice?

Tags: identify-this-game

Does anyone recognize these game pieces?

[image]
[image]

I found them at a second hand store and having a hard time finding where they come from.

Here is what I have (all wooden):

4 blue roosters (?)
4 green pine trees
4 red ducks
4 brown rabbits
3 yellow chickens (?)
3 white sheep
1 normal size die with each color
1 large die with each symbol on its sides

I may be missing 1 sheep and 1 chicken and I don't know if it came with a board or not.

Any help in identifying these is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not certain at all so this is a comment not an answer.  There seem to be lots of variants of Animal Upon Animal, some like this one (https://www.amazon.com/HABA-Animal-Upon-Climbers-Swiss-Inspired/dp/B01BMSBYK8) include trees.  The numbers of components looks about right.  Is it possible made a custom version?

Comment: @StartPlayer You may be on to it! I've seen versions of those before, but never with trees or the large die, so that made me think it might be something new. Your link certainly has trees and pine trees at that. The double dice would be a new element to that type of game but I think I can narrow my search and continue to hunt for this specific version. If nothing comes up, then you might be right about it being custom.

Answer (score 3):

(Caveat: This is not a complete answer.)

I recognize several of the animal figurines; I had them as a kid, but not as part of any game (and not with the large die). They were part of Discovery Toys' ["Wooden Playtime" set](https://picclick.com/VTG-1983-Wooden-Playtime-Animals-Trees-People-Discovery-393390545677.html) (1983):

[image]

The small color-dot die is also associated with Discovery Toys and/or Ravensburger; for example, it's used in [*Snail's Pace Race*](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2767/snails-pace-race) (1985).

However, I have never seen the big wooden die before.

So basically, you might look for answers in the mid-1980s, in Germany, possibly Ravensburger (that is, [Otto Maier Verlag](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamepublisher/99/otto-maier-verlag/), since the modern Ravensburger is apparently a different entity reincorporated in 1992 with the same logo), and almost certainly a game for young children (in case there was any doubt on that count :)).

Comment: This is a great lead! Thank you very much. This is definitely halfway there with those exact same pieces, so now I'm just looking to hunt down where the large die comes from. If I find it, I'll accept this answer for sure.